# How can I solve a compilation error when declaring a map of structs?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am getting the following error with `map` of `struct`s:

> `Error: invalid types ‘int[unsigned int]’ for array subscript`.

#### My Code:

```
  typedef struct {
      std::string s;
  }re;
  re r;
  std::map<unsigned int, r> var;

  int main(){
   struct re{
       string s;
   }re;
   re.s="hello";
   var[10]=re;}
```

---

#### Update, following some answers:

If I change `r` to `re` in `map`'s declaration, then I get the error:

> `error: no match for ‘operator=’ in var.std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[] [with _Key = unsigned int, _Tp = re, _Compare = std::less<unsigned int>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const unsigned int, re> >, std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type = re, std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = unsigned int]((*(const key_type*)(& o) = re’`

Comment: Your map declaration is invalid.

Comment: why are you declaring the struct twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`r` is an *instance* of the `re` type, which is a type alias for the `struct` you define. Therefore, you should change this:

```
std::map<unsigned int, r> var;
```

Into his:

```
std::map<unsigned int, re> var;
//                     ^^
```

Also notice, that in the `main()` procedure you are re-defining the `re` structure, when you most likely just wanted to create an instance of it:

```
int main() {
    re r;
    r.s="hello";
    var[10]=r;
}
```

Thus, putting everything together:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>

// Avoid this old C style of defining structs. Prefer the
// C++ style I am showing below...
/*
typedef struct {
      std::string s;
  } re;
*/

struct re
{
    std::string s;
};

int main() {
    std::map<unsigned int, re> var;
    re r;
    r.s="hello";
    var[10]=r;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. But if i change r to re then I get the error as mentioned in the edited post

Comment: @user1778824: It works for me. Just copy-paste the code in the last part of my answer and it should compile

Answer (score 2):

The map needs a type for the mapped_type, and you are giving it `re` instance `r`. You need

```
std::map<unsigned int, re> var;
```

Your code can be simplified further:

```
struct re {
  std::string s;
};

int main()
{
  re r;
  std::map<unsigned int, re> var;

  r.s="hello";
  var[10]=r;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. But if i change r to re then I get the error as mentioned in the edited post

Comment: @user1778824: That's because your code contains other errors.  That doesn't change the fact that using a variable as a template argument is still wrong.

Comment: @user1778824 there is a working version of your code in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can just say

```
struct re { std::string s; };
```

in C++. The `typedef struct {...} name;` is a C-ism.

In your map, you must give a type instead of a variable

```
std::map<unsigned int, re> var;
```

The error you get in the `main()` function, is because you try to assign a variable of a different type `main()::struct re` to the map element `10`, which is of type `typedef struct { ... } re`.

To summarize, `struct re` in main is not the same type as the `typedef ... re` in the global scope.

Answer (score 1):

please change

```
std::map<unsigned int, r> var;
```

into

```
 std::map<unsigned int, re> var;
```

you define map of some type, in `<>` you passes types that you want map to "map" (define mapping between them).

This is all code snippet:

```
#include <map>
typedef struct {
    std::string s;
}re;
re r;
std::map<unsigned int, re> var;

int f(int argc, char** argv) {
   re res; 
   res.s="hello";
   var[10]=res;
   //and if you want that global variable
   r.s="global variable";
   var[1]=r; 

   return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. But if i change r to re then I get the error as mentioned in the edited post

Comment: @user1778824 it is OK, just don't write re declaration again, see my edit, copy & paste, into appropriate (the same() places!

Answer (score 1):

Comments inline describe how to fix your code.

```
#include <string>
#include <map>

//typedef struct { // This is from C. Use the C++ way...
struct re_type {
    std::string s;
//} re; // See above
    };

// re r; // You do not need a global instance

// std::map<unsigned int, r> var; // `r` was an instance.
// The map declaration needs a type:
std::map<unsigned int, re_type> var; // Note: This is global and should probably be 
                                     // moved into main()

int main(){
    // struct re{  // No need to redeclare the struct here
    //    string s;
    // }re;

    re_type re; // Create a local instance

    re.s="hello";
    var[10]=re;
}
```

`re`, `r`, `s` and `var` do not appear to be descriptive identifiers. Using meaningful identifiers will make your code easier to read and maintain and will even help you to understand compilation errors as they arise.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct {
    std::string s;
} re;
```

Then later:

```
std::map<unsigned int, r> var;
```

Nah. The template needs the ***type*** but you're giving it a variable. Change it to

```
std::map<unsigned int, re> var;
```

and it will work fine.

Comment: Thanks for replying. But if i change r to re then I get the error as mentioned in the edited post

Comment: @user1778824 In this case, I advise you to read the documentation of `std::map`.